# Error de consulta fetch_array(), en php al hacer un consulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mvc, session

Hola trato de hacer una consulta y utilizar los campos de su resultado pero obtengo un error que en la conexión anterior no había ocurrido.

tengo la clase entidad_db.php donde obtengo mi conexión.

```
class Entidad_db {
/* private $conexion;
  private $executeQuery;
  private $result;
  private $sql; */

private $table;
private $conectar;
private $db;

/* private $result;
  private $query; */

function __construct($table) {
    require_once 'Conexion.php';
    $this->table = (string) $table;
    $this->conectar = new Conexion();
    $this->db = $this->conectar->openConexion();
}

function getConectar() {
    return $this->conectar;
}

function cerrarConectar() {
    $this->conectar->closeConexion();
}

function getDb() {
    return $this->db;
}
```

}

posteriormente estoy aplicando la respectiva herencia de esa clase a la clase UsuarioModel.php para utilizar todos sus metodos.

```
class UsuarioModel extends Modelo_db{

private $table;
function __construct() {
    $this->table = "usuario";
    parent::__construct($this->table);
}
function getUsuario($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario='".$id."';";
    $res = $this->getDb()->query($sql);
    $res->fetch_array();
    return $res;
}
```

}

inicialmente desde otra clase Usuario.php tambien aplico la misma herencia de Entidad_db.php para hacer lo mismo y obtener la herencia de todos sus  metodos y poder ejecutar consultas y llenar mi modelo Usuario.php con todos loc campos que mi consulta obtiene a sus respectivos atributos.

```
class Usuario extends Entidad_db {

private $id_usuario;
private $id_rol;
private $rut;
private $clave;
private $nombre;
private $apellido;
private $actividad;

function __construct() {
    $table = "usuario";
    parent::__construct($table);
}

function getId_usuario() {
    return $this->id_usuario;
}

function getId_rol() {
    return $this->id_rol;
}

function getRut() {
    return $this->rut;
}

function getClave() {
    return $this->clave;
}

function getNombre() {
    return $this->nombre;
}

function getApellido() {
    return $this->apellido;
}

function getActividad() {
    return $this->actividad;
}

public function setId_usuario($id_usuario) {
    $this->id_usuario = $id_usuario;
}

function setId_rol($id_rol) {
    $this->id_rol = $id_rol;
}

function setRut($rut) {
    $this->rut = $rut;
}

function setClave($clave) {
    $this->clave = $clave;
}

function setNombre($nombre) {
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
}

function setApellido($apellido) {
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
}

function setActividad($actividad) {
    $this->actividad = $actividad;
}

function save() {
    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` VALUES(''," . $this->id_rol . ","
            . $this->rut . ",'"
            . $this->clave . "','"
            . $this->nombre . "','"
            . $this->apellido . "',"
            . "1);";
    $guardar = $this->getDb()->query($this->sql);
    return $guardar;
}

function Login() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE `rut` = '" . $this->id_usuario . "' AND clave='" . $this->clave . "';";
    $res = $this->getDb()->query($sql);
    $row = $res->num_rows;

    if ($row > 0) {
        $loginDatos = $res->fetch_array();
        $this->cerrarConectar();
        $userModel = new UsuarioModel();
        $rowUser = $userModel->getUsuario($loginDatos[0]);

        $u = new Usuario();

        $u->setId_usuario($rowUser[0]);
        $u->setId_rol($rowUser[1]);
        $u->setRut($rowUser[2]);
        $u->setClave($rowUser[3]);
        $u->setNombre($rowUser[4]);
        $u->setApellido($rowUser[5]);
        $u->setActividad($rowUser[6]);
        $_SESSION['MyUser'] = $u->getNombre();
        $this->cerrarConectar();
        $dato = true;
    } else {
        $dato = false;
    }
    return $dato;
}
```

}

Bueno es aquí cuando ejecuto el metodo login(), buscando hacer el login y si el usuario y clave son correctas poder obtener todos los datos de esa base para después reutilizar sus campos en mi pagina, y como resultado no obtengo información de ningún dato y mi pagina expulsa un error desconocido.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\model\UsuarioModel.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\model\Usuario.php(94): UsuarioModel->getUsuario('3') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\controller\UsuarioController.php(56): Usuario->Login() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\core\controladorFront.php(27): UsuarioController->loginUsuario() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\core\controladorFront.php(32): loadAction(Object(UsuarioController), 'loginUsuario') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\index.php(15): executeAccion(Object(UsuarioController)) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Transparente\model\UsuarioModel.php on line 16
```

Comment: en tu modelo esto esta dando error fetch_array()

Comment: si exactamente me causa ese error , pero en la anterior consulta que hago no pasa eso , el fecth_array() me devuelve resultados